# "All of which I" or "All of which I've"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

The sentence I'm trying to write is

> I have extensive experience in circuit analyses and electrical theory from courses that I’ve taken including (class A), (class B), (class C), and (class D), **all of which I received** an A+ in.

Should it be "all of which *I've* received", or is it okay the way it is written? It doesn't flow off the tongue easily for me. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The larger issue here is whether to include specific courses and grades on a resume or application.  There is room for debate here, but it would put me off as I scanned a stack of resumes.  If the potential employer actually wants those details, they will ask for official transcripts.  Until then, just list degree and GPA and be done.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not be "all of which I've received" and neither is it OK the way it was written.

“… in all of which I received an A+ would be much better

“… in each of which I received an A+ would be better still

Comment: We prefer longer answers, especially ones that provide references.